# Converting table of Ms word into image using java

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I want to know how to extract table data as image in Ms word.
I can only find a way to extract the image data in the table as shown below.

```
public void test(String filePath) {

    try(XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(filePath))) {
        List<XWPFTable> tables = doc.getTables();
        for (XWPFTable xwpfTable : tables) {
            List<XWPFTableRow> rows = xwpfTable.getRows();

            for (XWPFTableRow xwpfTableRow : rows) {
                List<XWPFTableCell> cells = xwpfTableRow.getTableCells();

                for (XWPFTableCell xwpfTableCell : cells) {

                    if (xwpfTableCell != null) {


                        for (XWPFParagraph p : xwpfTableCell.getParagraphs()) {

                            for (XWPFRun run : p.getRuns()) {

                                for (XWPFPicture pic : run.getEmbeddedPictures()) {
                                    byte[] pictureData = pic.getPictureData().getData();
                                    System.out.println("picture : " + pic.getDescription());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

The language I use is Java.

Comment: You mean: a table rendered in Word with styled text, all that rendered in an image, say .png? Rendering in an image is no problem, inside a `BufferedImage`'s `createGraphics` ... `disposeGraphics`.

Comment: @JoopEggen This is the way I didn't think. Thank you for a good clue.